# Google Sheets script: loop runs properly once, then throws an error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Following is a standalone Google Apps script I cobbled together (with very little programming experience). Basically, it's supposed to cycle through all the Google Sheets workbooks in a Google Drive folder. For each workbook, it hides all sheets except the one named "Current;" downloads that sheet as a PDF; then creates a new blank "Current" sheet. This worked perfectly 8 months ago. But now it works for the first workbook in the folder, then fails on the second workbook with the error, "Exception: You can't hide all the sheets in a document" on this line:

```
if(sheets[i].getName()!="Current"){ sheets[i].hideSheet() }
```

Here's the complete script:

```
function saveInvoice() {

  //This script will process all the mentor invoices as follows:
  // 1. Get all the workbooks in the invoice folder
  // 2. For each workbook:
  //    a. Turn the "Current" tab into a PDF and save it in the designated folder with filename "[mentor name]-[date].pdf"
  //    b. Rename "Current" to today's date
  //    c. Make a new "Current" from the blank invoice template
  //    d. Move the new Current to be the leftmost tab in the workbook
  //    e. Lather, rinse, repeat.


//get the speadsheets in the current folder
var invoiceFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Fake invoices for testing").next(); //THE FOLDER NAME NEEDS TO BE UPDATED EVERY YEAR! This is the folder with the speadsheet invoices.
var invoiceSheets = invoiceFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
Logger.log(invoiceSheets)


while (invoiceSheets.hasNext()) // Loops through all Workbooks inside the folder.
  {
    var workBook = invoiceSheets.next(); //get the next workbook
    Logger.log("Workbook:"+workBook)


    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook).getSheetByName("Current");
    Logger.log("spreadSheet:"+spreadSheet)


      // download the "Current" invoice sheet as a PDF named [mentor name (from cell A1)]+current date].pdf

        var today=new Date();
        var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd") //get today's date and format it

      
        var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook).getSheets(); //get all the sheets

        var ltrsht = SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook).getSheetByName("Current");


        //now cycle through the sheets in the workbook and hide all except "Current." Have to hide them b/c no way to d.l. a single sheet
        for(var i =0;i<sheets.length;i++){
          if(sheets[i].getName()!="Current"){ sheets[i].hideSheet() }
          }
          var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(workBook.getId());
          var theBlob = pdf.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(ltrsht.getRange("A1").getValue()+"-"+date+".pdf"); //create the file name
          var folderID = "13KcgTUC3sw1aAa3xQWY6FkY6GwAH0cT7"; // Folder id to save in a folder **NEEDS TO BE UPDATED EVERY YEAR**
          var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID); //get the target folder
          var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob); //save the file
      


      //now unhide the other sheets
       var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook).getSheets(); //get all the sheets
        for(var i =0;i<sheets.length;i++){
          if(sheets[i].getName()!="Current"){ sheets[i].showSheet() }
          }


      //change name of "Current" sheet to today's date
      SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook).getSheetByName("Current").setName(date);


      //Make a copy of the "Blank" sheet and rename it "Current"
      var source = SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook);
      Logger.log("source:"+source)
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook).getSheetByName('Blank');

      sheet.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook)).setName('Current');


      // Make the new Current sheet the leftmost tab in the Workbook
      // var tab = SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook).getSheetByName('Current');
      // SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook).setActiveSheet(tab);
      // SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook).moveActiveSheet(1);

      const dss = SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook);
      const sh = dss.getSheetByName('Current').activate();
      dss.moveActiveSheet(0);
  }

}
```

I suspect I'm missing something obvious because of my inexperience. What's especially puzzling is the fact that this same script worked flawlessly a year ago. Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a result of the "Current" sheet either being hidden or not existing in the given Spreadsheet. Modified it to log anytime a spreadsheet doesn't have a "Current" sheet and to show the "Current" sheet before hiding the rest. I also made some improvements that should speed things up with fewer calls to SpreadsheetApp.

```js
function saveInvoice() {

  //This script will process all the mentor invoices as follows:
  // 1. Get all the workbooks in the invoice folder
  // 2. For each workbook:
  //    a. Turn the "Current" tab into a PDF and save it in the designated folder with filename "[mentor name]-[date].pdf"
  //    b. Rename "Current" to today's date
  //    c. Make a new "Current" from the blank invoice template
  //    d. Move the new Current to be the leftmost tab in the workbook
  //    e. Lather, rinse, repeat.


  //get the speadsheets in the current folder
  var invoiceFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Fake invoices for testing").next(); //THE FOLDER NAME NEEDS TO BE UPDATED EVERY YEAR! This is the folder with the speadsheet invoices.
  var invoiceSheets = invoiceFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  Logger.log(invoiceSheets)

  // Loops through all Workbooks inside the folder.
  while (invoiceSheets.hasNext()) {
    var workBook = invoiceSheets.next(); //get the next workbook
    Logger.log("Workbook:" + workBook)


    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook);
    var ltrsht = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Current");
    Logger.log("spreadSheet:" + ltrsht)

    if (!ltrsht) {
      Logger.log("Current invoice not found:" + spreadSheet);
    } else {
      // download the "Current" invoice sheet as a PDF named [mentor name (from cell A1)]+current date].pdf

      var today = new Date();
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd") //get today's date and format it


      var sheets = spreadSheet.getSheets(); //get all the sheets


      //now cycle through the sheets in the workbook and hide all except "Current." Have to hide them b/c no way to d.l. a single sheet
      ltrsht.showSheet();
      for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
        if (sheets[i].getName() != "Current") {
          sheets[i].hideSheet()
        }
      }
      var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(workBook.getId());
      var theBlob = pdf.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(ltrsht.getRange("A1").getValue() + "-" + date + ".pdf"); //create the file name
      var folderID = "13KcgTUC3sw1aAa3xQWY6FkY6GwAH0cT7"; // Folder id to save in a folder **NEEDS TO BE UPDATED EVERY YEAR**
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID); //get the target folder
      var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob); //save the file



      //now unhide the other sheets
      for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
        if (sheets[i].getName() != "Current") {
          sheets[i].showSheet();
        }
      }


      //change name of "Current" sheet to today's date
      ltrsht.setName(date);


      //Make a copy of the "Blank" sheet and rename it "Current"
      Logger.log("source:" + spreadSheet)
      var blank = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Blank');

      var sh = blank.copyTo(spreadSheet).setName('Current');


      // Make the new Current sheet the leftmost tab in the Workbook
      // var tab = SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook).getSheetByName('Current');
      // SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook).setActiveSheet(tab);
      // SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook).moveActiveSheet(1);

      sh.activate();
      spreadSheet.moveActiveSheet(0);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! You're right about the underlying spreadsheets and the "Current" tab being part of the problem. Anyway, your revised code works perfectly (and speedier than mine did). So thanks very much!